# Adding location to a separate config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a web.config file with a lot of sections like this:

```
<location path="folder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Can this be separate it into a different file and then called in the web.config?, this will just make it cleaner in our web.config file to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate it out into a separate web.config and then put the new config file in the appropriate folder. So the new web.config is in that same folder that was specified in the `path`. The new file would look like:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`configSource` (see docs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) attribute on the `authorization` tag to import a common config file for all the locations.

See [Reducing authorization Redundancy in Web.config](http://asynchrony.blogspot.com/2008/12/reducing-authorization-redundancy-in.html)  (blog post).

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried ConfigSource ?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) : Gets or sets the name of the include file in which the associated configuration section is defined, if such a file exists.

http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx